# Generate CSV from Ruby results

Tags: ruby, csv

I currently have this script that generates usernames from a given CSV. Rather than printing these results to the console, how can I write a new CSV with these results?

This is the script I currently have, runs with no errors. I am assuming if I write a new CSV in the do |row| block it is going to create x amount of new files which I do not want.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('data.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  id = row['id']
  fn = row['first_name']
  ln = row['last_name']
  p fn[0] + ln + id[3,8]
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ **never** use `+` to concatenate strings in Ruby, it’s a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just manage the CSV file to write around the reading:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('data.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    id = row['id']
    fn = row['first_name']
    ln = row['last_name']
    csv << [fn[0], ln, id[3,8]]
    # or, to output it as a single column:
    # csv << ["#{fn[0]}#{ln}#{id[3,8]}"]
  end
end
```

[Writing CSV to a file](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File).

Comment: Instead of it outputting to three different columns how can I make it so it is one string? I tried replacing commas with plus signs but get a nil error.

Comment: Updated an answer :: use string interpolation.